# PHP How to code shopping cart with special description?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a $cart array(), it's a session variable before posting to database.

```
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'price' => string '10' (length=2)
      'qty' => int 2
      'item_desc' => string 'Fast Food 01' (length=12)
      'special_desc' => string '' (length=0)
  '1S' => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '1' (length=2)
      'price' => string '10' (length=2)
      'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
      'item_desc' => string 'Fast Food 01' (length=12)
      'special_desc' => string 'Special Cook style 1' (length=3)
```

As the example, the item id is "1", but to avoid conflict of duplicate key, I put "S" to indicate it's an array element with special description.

This is my current coding

```
...
if (array_key_exists($item_id, $cart)) {
  $key_item_id = $item_id . 'S';
}

$cart[$key_item_id] = array('id' => $item_id, 'price' => $price, 'qty' => $qty, 'item_desc' => $item_desc, 'special_desc' => $special_desc);
...
```

However, there may be a possibility that there are more than one special descriptions, so I think it should have a counter number after and "S" e.g. "1S1" to represent item id "1" with special descriptions style 1, "1S2" with special description style 2 and so on.

```
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'price' => string '10' (length=2)
      'qty' => int 2
      'item_desc' => string 'Fast Food 01' (length=12)
      'special_desc' => string '' (length=0)
  '1S1' => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '1' (length=2)
      'price' => string '10' (length=2)
      'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
      'item_desc' => string 'Fast Food 01' (length=12)
      'special_desc' => string 'Special Cook style 1' (length=3)

  '1S2' => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => string '1' (length=2)
      'price' => string '10' (length=2)
      'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
      'item_desc' => string 'Fast Food 01' (length=12)
      'special_desc' => string 'Special Cook style 2' (length=3)
```

My question is how to "count" the $cart that how many item id "1" with special description so I can realize the current counter of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Well I would have 1 solution but it would work only with ID 1 with ID2 it would not be clear

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea with keys. I think you should store all items of `same ID` in array item with one key.

```
1 => 
array (size=4)
  'price' => string '10' (length=2)
  'qty' => int 2
  'item_desc' => string 'Fast Food 01' (length=12)
  'special_desc' => string '' (length=0)
array (size=4)
  'price' => string '10' (length=2)
  'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
  'item_desc' => string 'Fast Food 01' (length=12)
  'special_desc' => string 'Special Cook style 1' (length=3)
array (size=4)
  'price' => string '10' (length=2)
  'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
  'item_desc' => string 'Fast Food 01' (length=12)
  'special_desc' => string 'Special Cook style 2' (length=3)`
```

Going further you can add key `total_quantity` and `special_items_quantity` and increase/decrease them when adding new items to array:

```
1 => 
total_quantity => 4    // now it is 4
special_items_quantity => 2    // now it is 2
array (size=4)
  'price' => string '10' (length=2)
  'qty' => int 2
  'item_desc' => string 'Fast Food 01' (length=12)
  'special_desc' => string '' (length=0)
array (size=4)
  'price' => string '10' (length=2)
  'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
  'item_desc' => string 'Fast Food 01' (length=12)
  'special_desc' => string 'Special Cook style 1' (length=3)
array (size=4)
  'price' => string '10' (length=2)
  'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
  'item_desc' => string 'Fast Food 01' (length=12)
  'special_desc' => string 'Special Cook style 2' (length=3)`
```

Comment: If I used array structure as yours, let's say I want to delete the element with "special cook style 1", how to do it?, what can I use to reference to the specific element?

Comment: Good question) Didn't think of it) Easiest way is to use `array_search` for each sub-array.

Answer (score 1):

By setting the value of `$index` to your product id, `$cnt` will get the total quantity of normal and special orders for that product:

```
$index = 1;
$cnt = array('total' => 0, 'normal' => 0,  'special' => 0);
array_walk($arr, function ($i, $k) use(&$cnt, $index){
    if ($i['id'] == $index){
        $cnt['total'] += $i['qty'];
        if ((string)$k == (string)$index) $cnt['normal'] += $i['qty'];
        else $cnt['special'] += $i['qty'];
    }
});
print_r($cnt);
```

Note: This solution requires PHP 5.3 or later.

Answer (score -1):

Wow , that complex for nothing.... you should use an other method ...

also, you can try something like this:

```
$count = 0;

foreach($cart as $item){

    if(!empty($item['special_desc'])) $count++;
}

// count is the number of special_desc in the $cart array...
```